# Enable textfield when selecting option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, jquery-ui-selectmenu

The following code lets you:
1. Select a city you want to travel from. Selecting a city enables the next control.
2. Select a city you want to travel to. Selecting a city enables the next control
3. Select the date you want to leave.

The code works nicely, except for when you select a city in the *travel_to*-list that comes directly after the city you chose in the *travel_from*-list. I cant figure out why. I.e: if you select "Naples", in the *travel_from*-controller and "Palermo" in the *travel_to-controller*, the *travel_from_date* is not enabled.

```js
  //Holds the names of all the cities
 var allCities = ["Naples", "Palermo", "Cagliari", "Barcelona", "Malaga", "Rio de Janeiro"];
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#travel_from, #travel_to").selectmenu();
   //Disables the travel_from_date-input field   
   $("#travel_from_date").prop("disabled", true);
   $("#travel_to").selectmenu("disable");

   $("#travel_from").on("selectmenuchange", function(event, ui) {
     var cities = allCities.slice();
     var selectedCity = $(this).val();
     var index = cities.indexOf(selectedCity);
     for (i = index; i > -1; i--) {
       cities.splice(i, 1);
     }
     $("#travel_to").selectmenu('destroy');
     $("#travel_to").selectmenu();
     $("#travel_to option").remove();
     $("#travel_to").append($('<option selected disabled></option').html("Where to?"));
     $.each(cities, function(val, text) {
       $("#travel_to").append(
         $('<option></option>').val(text).html(text)
       );
     });
     $("#travel_to option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
     $("#travel_to").selectmenu("enable");
   });

   $("#travel_to").on("selectmenuchange", function(event, ui) {
     $("#travel_from_date").prop("disabled", false);
   });
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form class="orderform">
  <fieldset>
    <h1>Book your voayage</h1>
    <select id="travel_from">
      <option disabled selected hidden>Where from?</option>
      <option>Naples</option>
      <option>Palermo</option>
      <option>Cagliari</option>
      <option>Barcelona</option>
      <option>Malaga</option>
      <option disabled>Rio de Janeiro</option>
    </select>

    <select id="travel_to">
      <option disabled selected hidden>Where to?</option>
    </select>

    <hr>

    <input id="travel_from_date" title="When do you want to leave?" type="text" name="travel_from_date" placeholder="Outbound" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Does it work any better if you comment out line with `cities.splice(i, 1);`?

Comment: Well, then the second dropdown wont show the proper values. I want the second dropdown to show only the cities that come after the city selected in the first dropdown.

Comment: Of course, my mistake. Destination select is not `nullable` and its value is always determined. I think that you have conflicting requirements: either destination select is nullable and next control initially disabled OR it is not nullable thus next control must be enabled.

Comment: It dosent seem like it registers the event at all.  
If I try to log the selected object, nothing happens when the selected cities are neighbouring.  

`$( "#travel_to" ).on( "selectmenuchange", function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui);
        $( "#travel_from_date" ).prop("disabled", false);
    });`

Comment: In other words, try not disabling first option ("Where to?") in destination select: `$("#travel_to").append($('<option selected></option').html("Where to?"));`. If that's not what you want then enable next control as soon as you enable destination select.

Comment: Enabling ("Where to?") would work, but it is not my desired design. How would I go about enabling it on destenation select? I tried, but I couldn't make it work. Have you made it work? Would you mind sharing the code?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get your idea. I would be glad to help you but first - do you understand my comment about nullable select?